# how to stop ViewPager fragment auto Initialize

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tabview

I have 3 fragments; when I start the app all the fragments are getting data from the server at the same time, but I need something like that [image: youtube view pager fragment]

When the user slides the tab then the fragment starts downloading data from the server,

in my case, all fragments start asynctask at the same time, so if you have slow internet then the app is going down

```
public class HeadLineFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60;
private static final String DW_HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://rss.dw.de/xml/rss-urd-all";
protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;
protected RadioButton mLinearLayoutRadioButton;
protected RadioButton mGridLayoutRadioButton;
protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
protected RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

protected ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList();
protected ArrayList<String> ImageURLS = new ArrayList<>();
protected ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList();
protected ArrayList<RssItem> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
private TextView textView;
private Context context;
private Elements metalinks;
private String mImageURL;
private Document documentImage;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private int mItemNumber;
private myPagerAdupter _myPagerAdupter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setRetainInstance(true);
    this._myPagerAdupter= new myPagerAdupter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.head_line_fragment, container, false);


    new LoadRssFeedsItems().execute(DW_HOME_PAGE_URL);
    this.context = rootView.getContext();



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Progressbar);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);

    LoadRssFeedsItems loadRssFeedsItems = new LoadRssFeedsItems();

    loadRssFeedsItems.setCircularProgressView(mProgressBar);




    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
    }
    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);


    return rootView;
}


public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;

    if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        default:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


private enum LayoutManagerType {
    GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
    LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
}


private class LoadRssFeedsItems extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private String mTitle, mDescription, mLink, mPubDate;

    private ProgressBar circularProgressView;

    public void setCircularProgressView(ProgressBar circularProgressView) {
        this.circularProgressView = circularProgressView;
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            Document rssDocument = Jsoup.connect(DW_HOME_PAGE_URL).timeout(Constants.TIME_OUT).ignoreContentType(true).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();


            Elements mItems = rssDocument.select(Constants.ITEM);
            RssItem rssItem;
            mItemNumber = 0;
            for (Element element : mItems) {

                mItemNumber++;
                mTitle = element.select("title").first().text();
                mDescription = element.select("description").first().text();
                mLink = element.select("link").first().text();
                mPubDate = element.select("pubDate").first().text();


                Log.i(TAG, "Item title: " + (mTitle == null ? "N/A" : mTitle));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item Description: " + (mDescription == null ? "N/A" : mDescription));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item link: " + (mLink == null ? "N/A" : mLink));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item data: " + (mPubDate == null ? "N/A" : mPubDate));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item image link: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));
                Log.i(TAG, "item: : " + mItemNumber);
                rssItem = new RssItem(mTitle, mDescription, mPubDate, mLink, mItemNumber, getContext());
                mDataset.add(rssItem);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "d";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... value) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(value);
        if (circularProgressView != null) {

            circularProgressView.setProgress(value[0]);
        }

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (mDataset.isEmpty()) {
            Snackbar mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Unable to connect  Home page", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            new LoadRssFeedsItems().execute(Constants.HALAT_HAZRA);


                        }
                    });
            mSnackbar.show();
        } else {
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mDataset);
            Log.i(TAG, "m data set size in current affairs: " + mDataset.size());

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            getImageUrls get_ImageUrls = new getImageUrls();

            get_ImageUrls.execute();
        }
    }
}

private class getImageUrls extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String mLink;
    String mLastHalfUrl;
    String url;
    int dash_A_index;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), "Loding Photos...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Item image link in seacond thread: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));

        try {



            for (int i = 0; i < mDataset.size(); i++) {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                mLink = mDataset.get(i).getLink();

                dash_A_index = mLink.indexOf(Constants.BACK_SLASH_A);
                mLastHalfUrl = mLink.substring(dash_A_index);
                url = mLink.replace(Constants.BASE_URL, "");
                url = url.replace(mLastHalfUrl, "");
                url = StringUtils.replaceEach(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"), new String[]{"+", "*", "%7E"}, new String[]{"%20", "%2A", "~"});
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
                url = sb.append(mLastHalfUrl).toString();
                url = Constants.BASE_URL + url;
                documentImage = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(Constants.TIME_OUT).get();
                metalinks = documentImage.select(Constants.MATA_PROPTY_IMAGE);
                mImageURL = metalinks.attr(Constants.CONTENT);
                Log.i(TAG, "Item image link in seacond thread home page: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));
                mDataset.get(i).setImageUrl(mImageURL);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        Constants.IS_GET_IMAGE_URL=true;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MaterialTabListener {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = "viewPge";
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter RecyclerViewadapter;
    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    private String[] tabs;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);


        tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);


        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdupter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));

        this.mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(
                    tabHost.newTab().setText(tabs[i])


                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
        @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {



        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }


    public void addFragment() {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        healthNewFragment recylerViewFragment = new healthNewFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_contaner, recylerViewFragment, "TAG_FRAGEMENT");
        //  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
   }
```

**Fragment 2**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    this.context = getContext();
    Log.i(TAG_LIFE, "Inside onCreat");


    new LoadRssFeedsItems().execute(DW_HOME_PAGE_URL);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG_LIFE, "Inside onViewCreated");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.head_line_fragment, container, false);

    this.context = rootView.getContext();


    Log.i(TAG_LIFE, "Inside onCreateView");

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
    }
    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);


    return rootView;
}


public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;


    if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        default:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


private enum LayoutManagerType {
    GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
    LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
}



private class LoadRssFeedsItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String mTitle, mDescription, mLink, mPubDate;

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            Document rssDocument = Jsoup.connect(Constants.HEALTH).timeout(Constants.TIME_OUT).ignoreContentType(true).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();

            Document imageURLDocument;


            Elements mItems = rssDocument.select(Constants.ITEM);
            RssItem rssItem;
            String mLastHalfUrl;
            String url;
            int dash_A_index;
            int i = 0;
            for (Element element : mItems) {
                i++;
                mTitle = element.select("title").first().text();
                mDescription = element.select("description").first().text();
                mLink = element.select("link").first().text();
                mPubDate = element.select("pubDate").first().text();
                Log.i(TAG, "Item title: " + (mTitle == null ? "N/A" : mTitle));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item Description: " + (mDescription == null ? "N/A" : mDescription));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item link: " + (mLink == null ? "N/A" : mLink));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item data: " + (mPubDate == null ? "N/A" : mPubDate));
                Log.i(TAG, "Item image link: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));
                Log.i(TAG, "int i : " + i);
                rssItem = new RssItem(mTitle, mDescription, mPubDate, mLink, i, getContext());
                mDataset.add(rssItem);

            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "d";
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (mDataset == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecction time out");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connecction time ou)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (mDataset.isEmpty()) {
            Snackbar mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Unable to connect Health", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            new LoadRssFeedsItems().execute(Constants.HALAT_HAZRA);


                        }
                    });
            mSnackbar.show();
        } else {
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mDataset);
            Log.i(TAG, "m data set size: " + mDataset.size());

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            getImageUrls get_ImageUrls = new getImageUrls();
            get_ImageUrls.execute();
        }
    }
}

private class getImageUrls extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String mLink;
    String mLastHalfUrl;
    String url;
    int dash_A_index;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Item image link in seacond thread: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));


        try {


            for (int i = 0; i < mDataset.size(); i++) {
                mLink = mDataset.get(i).getLink();
                dash_A_index = mLink.indexOf(Constants.BACK_SLASH_A);
                mLastHalfUrl = mLink.substring(dash_A_index);
                url = mLink.replace(Constants.BASE_URL, "");
                url = url.replace(mLastHalfUrl, "");
                url = StringUtils.replaceEach(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"), new String[]{"+", "*", "%7E"}, new String[]{"%20", "%2A", "~"});
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
                url = sb.append(mLastHalfUrl).toString();
                url = Constants.BASE_URL + url;
                documentImage = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                metalinks = documentImage.select(Constants.MATA_PROPTY_IMAGE);
                mImageURL = metalinks.attr(Constants.CONTENT);
                Log.i(TAG, "Item image link in seacond thread: " + (mImageURL == null ? "N/A" : mImageURL));
                mDataset.get(i).setImageUrl(mImageURL);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Answer (score 0):

Call your async task when your fragments are visble by adding below method and remove from CreateView. By using below method, your data will be loaded only when your tab is selected and your particular fragment is visible.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {

      new LoadRssFeedsItems().execute(DW_HOME_PAGE_URL);
    }
}
```